# New to x64 Assembly, not sure why user input is still 0

Tags: visual-studio, loops, assembly, x86-64, masm

My program is supposed to read a bunch of signed integers and display the largest and smallest entered. When zero is entered after the input, it will print but if the first value entered is 0, the program must end right away without displaying anything. Been stuck on figuring out how to store all of the numbers the user enters as it is just 0 when I test print, so I assume the values are getting destroyed. Haven't figured out the loop to compare the numbers yet because I've been banging my brain on that part for a good while and figuring out a botched way to get the sentinel working, but I'll get to it. Can someone hint to me what I'm doing wrong?

Output:

```
Enter a series of numbers:
100
250
500
0
Largest: 0
Smallest: 0
```

Source Code:

```
extrn DisplayString:          PROTO
extrn DisplayNewline:         PROTO
extrn ReadInt:                PROTO
extrn DisplayInt:           PROTO
extrn ExitProcess:            PROTO

.data
msg1            byte    'Enter a series of numbers: ', 0
largestMsg      byte    'Largest: ',0
smallestMsg     byte    'Smallest: ',0

.data?
input               byte    ?
smallest            word    ?
largest             word    ?           
numsEntered         byte    ?


.code

main        PROC

                ;Prepare for stacks
                sub     rsp, 32                 ;reserve shadow space
                push    rbp                     ;save non-volatile base pointer
                mov     rbp, rsp                ;make frame pointer for direct access
                mov     rcx, 100                ;get address of request
                lea     rbx, numsEntered        ;get address of array

                ;Print prompt
                lea     rcx, msg1               ;store in address the prompt
                call    DisplayString           ;print message
                call    DisplayNewline          ;print new line

                ;Get First input and compare to sentinel
                lea     rcx, input              ;point input to address
                call    readInt                 ;read user input
                push    rcx
                mov     r12b, input             ;store input in register
                cmp     r12b, 0                 ;compare input to sentinal
                je      Continue                ;if input = to sentinal exit code
                jg      asknum                  ;if input greater than sentinal jp to loop


asknum:         ;Read and compare user input until they enter 0
                lea     rcx, input              ;point input to address
                call    readInt                 ;read user input
                mov     r12b, input             ;store input in register
                cmp     input, 0                ;compare input to sentinal
                je      PrintLargest            ;if user types sentinal after inputs, jp to print largest num

                loop    asknum                  ;loop for user input

PrintLargest:
            lea     rcx, largestMsg             ;point to prompt address
            call    DisplayString               ;print prompt largestMsg
            lea     rcx, largest                ;point largest integer to address
            call    DisplayInt                  ;print largest integer
            call    DisplayNewline              ;print new line
            jp      PrintSmallest               ;jump to calculate smallest integer

PrintSmallest:
            ;after printing largest, print the smallest
            lea     rcx, smallestMsg            ;point to prompt address
            call    DisplayString               ;print prompt smallestMsg
            lea     rcx, smallest               ;point smallest integer to address
            call    DisplayInt                  ;print smallest integer 
            jp      Continue                    ;jump to exit code

Continue:
        pop     rbp                     ;clear stack
        add     rsp, 32                 ;restore shadow space
        call    ExitProcess             ;exit code

main        ENDP
END

Output:
```

Comment: The code does not look like C++.  Is it assembly?

Comment: Yes, the code is assembly and is linked to a C++ file to get external functions for printing.[since it's not really important, I'll get rid of the c++ tag]

Comment: Are you sure your `DisplayInt` function takes an integer by reference (with a pointer arg), not by value?  If not, then do a `mov` load rather than an `lea` of the address.  (Probably not the problem, just the first weird thing I noticed.)  Also, having `readInt` return a value in RAX would be a better design, although passing an output arg pointer lets this function pass that to scanf.

Comment: I just double-checked in the .cpp file, it does take the integers by reference as so 

extern "C" void DisplayInt(int* pi)  //dword
{
 printf("%d ", *pi);
 //cout << *pi;
}

 Going back, I realized I should have set my values as dword as well. But I'll try returning my values in RAX a shot!